# JavaScript update element on different page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How would I take the input value from the text box and change it on on the element on another page in the web folder? For example, how can I edit an about me section from my admin page? I am using JavaScript and Firebase.

```
function uploadAbout() {
   var a = document.getElementById("aboutT").value;
   var txt=(a);
   document.getElementById("aboutme").value = a;
   alert(txt);
}
```

Comment: You will need to store the value somewhere, such as on the server, in your Firebase database, or in local storage, and then retrieve it from the other page.

Comment: Thanks, how can I go about doing that, saving and retrieving it from the firebase database?

Comment: If you're using Firebase, then I presume you're already using the database. If not, the Firebase database documentation has all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 

   var a = document.getElementById("aboutT").value;

   // Store
   localStorage.setItem("aboutVal", a);

   // Retrieve
   var b = localStorage.getItem("aboutVal");
   document.getElementById("aboutme").value = b;

}, false);
```

Comment: This answer seems to be ignoring the part of the question about "on another page in the web folder".